# Pandas: multiplying column conditional on its name meeting a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas in Python. An example of a dataframe I'm dealing with follows:

```
pd.DataFrame({"A1": [1,2,3], "A2": [1,2,3], "A3": [1,2,3], "A4": [1,2,3], "B1": [3,2,1], "B2": [3,2,1], "B3": [3,2,1], "B4": [3,2,1]})
```

I want to multiply the column by 10 if the column name ends with 4. So the desired output in this case would be

```
pd.DataFrame({"A1": [1,2,3], "A2": [1,2,3], "A3": [1,2,3], "A4": [10,20,30], "B1": [3,2,1], "B2": [3,2,1], "B3": [3,2,1], "B4": [30,20,10]})
```

Notice that only the columns A4 and B4 are changed.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative solution selecting columns to multiply with array.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A1": [1,2,3], "A2": [1,2,3], "A3": [1,2,3], "A4": [1,2,3], "B1": [3,2,1], "B2": [3,2,1], "B3": [3,2,1], "B4": [3,2,1]})

cols = [i for i in df.columns if i.endswith("4")]
df[cols] *= 10

df
```

Output:

```
    A1  A2  A3  A4  B1  B2  B3  B4
0   1   1   1   10  3   3   3   30
1   2   2   2   20  2   2   2   20
2   3   3   3   30  1   1   1   10
```

Compared to iloc there are some small time improvements on my setup:

1. 100 loops, best of 3: 2.45 ms per loop
2. 100 loops, best of 3: 2.04 ms per loop (Bharaths solution)

Answer (score 2):

Used `columns.str.endswith` and `iloc` to select the columns then multiply the value ie.

```
cols = df.columns.str.endswith('4')
df.iloc[:,cols] =  df.iloc[:,cols]*10
```

Output :

```
   A1  A2  A3  A4  B1  B2  B3  B4
0   1   1   1  10   3   3   3  30
1   2   2   2  20   2   2   2  20
2   3   3   3  30   1   1   1  10
```

We can also do short hand assignment i.e `df.iloc[:,cols] *=10`

Comment: Let us do this `df.iloc[:,cols] *=10`